# Loader in Mui Select

Tags: javascript, material-ui

This is my mui selection how to add the mui circle progression to the left of the selection field when the selected item is loaded so that the circle progression is turned off after the data is loaded.

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    value={age}
    label="Age"
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

i dont know i want to add this